# Generating plain text email with erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, erb, plaintext

I'm generating plain text emails using ActionMailer 3.0.9 and erb template. Everything goes well except that my emails contain backtraces of exceptions with characters like '<', '"' etc. which are changed onto '& lt;', '& quot;' etc.
So my question is: how to configure erb/mailer so it doesn't expand these characters into '&(...);'?

Comment: perhaps it's an unsafe string? try calling html_safe on the body.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, use `<%=raw ... %>` then your contents of the variable inside the <%= %> won't be escaped.